# How to convert java project to Maven project or similar

Tags: java, maven

I am currently creating an application for compiling multiple java projects in one go for programming assignments. As there are many different ways to submit java projects(e.g. as eclipse project, as netbeans project, as jar file) is there a plugin of something similar that you can easily import or use in a project that will convert a java project to a maven project so they can all be compiled in the same way rather then having to create functionality to allow the program to compile all different types of java projects?

If not to maven projects, is there another way to accomplish what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no such tool to mavenize just freestyle Java project just like that. Maven is based on some own conventions that are not necessarily common. It's not just about where Java files are, but also where the resources are (e.g. they can be at a same directory with Java files), where other assets are (e.g. WSDL files), what are these assets, how to handle them and how to use all this stuff to successfully build final package. I think there's no chance to have such universal tool that can do this.

I think the best scenario one can imagine here is to figure out some common assumptions about projects you have to build, e.g. they can only contain Java sources and just regular resources. Then you can implement some script or program that scans such simplified Java project to know where all these files are. And even then, what about dependencies? Should you scan Eclipse/Netbeans/IDEA specific files for them? It's really hard to even create these assumptions that make projects simple enough to auto-mavenize.

As I said, I really don't believe you can do something better than just enforce projects to be already Maven-managed.

Comment: ya because its something that is wrecking my head because i cant figure out away around this, because i need a way to compile different types of projects successfully really

Comment: Yea, I totally understand you. It's really hard unless you just enforce people to deliver Maven (or Ant, or anything) projects that you can handle in the same way, using the same tool.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if I understood your question exactly, but most IDE software (e.g. Eclipse, Netbeans etc) have plugins for Maven, in which you can "mavenize" a project from the right-click contextual menu under the "Configure" options.

Comment: +1 for the answer...ya that is exactly what i want to do, but i want to be able to click a button in my system. i dont want to have to go into eclipse every time i want to convert the project to a maven project. instead i want to be able to click a button in my system that will do the exact same thing

Comment: That would be very system dependent, I guess you could write a small batch file to create/change necessarily files, then execute the batch file but still you'll need to get your hands dirty. AFAIK there is no tool for fully automatizing just that.

Comment: When you use Spring Tool Suite, you can use Window > Show View > Project Explorer. Then IIRC you right click the project, then Configure > Convert to Maven. That will create your initial pom.xml and refactor the folders to the appropriate structure.

Answer (score 0):

As posdef said, Eclipse (with m2eclipse or iam) and IntelliJ can do that :

- http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-java-web-project-to-maven-project/
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Converting_Eclipse_Java_Project_to_Maven_Project

Your IDE have the information that such a plugin would needs. For instance, eclipse get its own files like .classpath, .settings/*. This is, as far as i know, proprietary format, so it's not easy to parse (although they are human readable).

I'm not sure you'll find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Spring STS** IDE (Spring Tool Suite), there is option to Convert Java/Dynamic Web Project into MAVEN Project. I believe the same you can accomplish through Eclipse as well once you have proper plug-ins

Right click on your Web project --> **Configure --> Convert to Maven Project**.

You will see **pom.xml** and other Mavenized features into your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same for Selenium Project. Hope will be useful

Please install TestNG and Maven in your system. Follow all Step 1 to Step 8, and Run your Project

Step:1 Right click on Java Project, click on Configure navigate to Convert to Maven Project.

Follow, figure 1.1 and figure 1.2

[image]

[image]

Step:2 Add all dependencies (required jars and plugins surefire-plugin for testing.xml)

[image]

How to add jars,

Way:1 Search in “https://mvnrepository.com/ “and add the repository

Way:2 Add jars from Local system (Chose either way1 or way2 or both if needed)
Create a folder (Say: lib) and place in the same directory

```
<dependency>
<groupId>selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
<systemPath>${basedir}/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar</systemPath>
<scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Step:3 Convert your class to testing class
[image]
[image]

Step:4 Edit testing.xml.

Provide the class Name save it

```
<suite name="Suite">
<test name="Test">
<classes>
<class name="test.java.CurseraTesting" />
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Step:5 Your class must contain Annotation @Test

If not, please add. See the below program,

```
package test.java;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class URL {
@Test
public void openUrl() throws InterruptedException{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\shivendra.pandey\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EjlbWbnFPOSK8QeylZ7ACw");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Search']")).sendKeys("sanfoundry");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.close();
}
}
```

Step:7 At the last verify all the setup’s TestNG, JDK

[image]

Step:8 Run your Project, click on Maven Test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse or Spring Tool Suite, right click on the project -> configure -> convert to maven project should convert your project to a maven project. You can check whether the project contains a pom.xml file. If yes then it is successfully converted.